# Any way to combine Theano tensor vectors similar to itertools.chain?

Tags: python, vector, concatenation, theano, chain

Does anyone know a way to combine tensor variable (containing vectors) in theano into another variable that references the originals, similar to itertools.chain?

Right now I can't get a result where `z = T.concatenate([x,y])` results where z.shape[0] = shape x.shape[0] + y.shape[0]. It always ends up with z having the same shape as x.

I'd appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a demonstration of `theano.tensor.concatenate`. You can use the `axis` parameter to adjust which dimension gets concatenated.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt

x, y = tt.matrices('x', 'y')
z1 = tt.concatenate([x, y])
z2 = tt.concatenate([x, y], axis=0)
z3 = tt.concatenate([x, y], axis=1)
f = theano.function([x, y], [z1, z2, z3])
for output in f([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]):
    print output.shape
```

This prints

```
(4L, 2L)
(4L, 2L)
(2L, 4L)
```

So I am unable to reproduce the stated behaviour. Using `z = tt.concatenate([x, y])` yields a single tensor that has `z.shape[0] = x.shape[0] + y.shape[0]` as desired.

Comment: Sorry, just got back to this. Just debugged it without optimizations, it seems the error is from somewhere higher up in the chain. I'm actually playing around with the Theano stacked autoencoder implementation by trying to combine the topmost output nodes from two different stacks. Apparently it's the lowest input nodes that are having some issues.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems the error was actually coming from a different point in the node tree. Concatenations were working properly using both thano.concatenate and the + operator.